# Why does my multimeter report a tiny current through a shunted 9-V battery?

Tags: current, multimeter, shunt

Why does my multimeter report a tiny current (microamps, if that) through a shunt resistor (e.g., 1.5 kΩ) or even a short placed across the terminals of a new 9-V battery?

The multimeter and all components are connected in *series*.

## Edit: Answer

It is likely that neither multimeter probe is connected to the common (COM) terminal of the multimeter. Note that the placement of this terminal (black) relative to other terminals (red) varies from multimeter to multimeter. Important: DO NOT retry the dead short test, especially after correcting the mistake or on µA/mA measurement ranges, to avoid blowing a fuse.

Comment: Which multimeter? How did you connect it? What settings used on multimeter? Did you already broke the fuse in it?

Comment: Should get 6 mA through the resistor. You'll need to show us how you're using the multimeter. You probably don't just select the current range (and DC) you may have to move the probes to a different socket. And if you did the dead short test first, replace the fuse as @Justme says.

Comment: `short placed across the terminals` ... this statement makes me think that the OP is placing the probes in parallel with the load

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. It’s a Mastech MS8217 multimeter. I connected it and all components in series. I switched from the ‘A’ terminal to the ‘µA/mA’ terminal as I reduced the measurement range in all cases. I used each of the corresponding DC(–) / AC(~) current measurement settings/options on the meter’s dial. I tried multiple alligator clips, wires, and – in attempt to reduce contact resistance – probing angles. I did the dead short test last. Even so, I cannot tell if the fuses are blown because they are covered in an opaque white layer.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. Problem solved.

Comment: @jsotola: No, but almost that stupid :)

Comment: Do we have to guess? Was the probe in the wrong hole?

Comment: @Justme: 1. no and 2. yes. I'm more ‘accustomed’ to COM being in the middle… Thanks guys, this actually was good help.

Comment: Happy to hear your problem has been solved! Could you please add details of how you connected things to the question, and add an answer explaining what solved your problem? Or, alternatively, delete your question. As it is now, your question isn't of any use to future readers ;)